# Deserializing Scala list with Jackson

Tags: scala, spring-boot, jackson

I have a case class that returns looks something like this

```
case class Response(
  @JsonDeserialize(contentAs = classOf[java.lang.Long])
  longList: List[Long] = null)
```

I have a customer ObjectMapper, that among other things registers DefaultScalaModule. According to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/FAQ, adding @JsonDeserialize should solve the issue, but it doesn't

The issue is in my tests, and I get the following error message

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
>
> at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:105)

Test class, list.head is what triggers the error

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  var testRestTemplate: TestRestTemplate = _
  @Autowired
  var objectMapper: ObjectMapper = _

  @Test 
  def test() : Unit = {
    val response = testRestTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.GET, classOf[Response])
    val list = response.getBody.longList
    val a = list.head
  }
}
```

Debugging tells me that my list is actually of type $colon$colon containing Integers