# Scala List[Int] becomes List<Object> in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have the following list defined within a Scala object:

```
object Foo {
    val bar = List(1, 2, 3)
}
```

Which seems to become a `scala.collection.immutable.List<Object>` when I try to use it from Java. As a consequence, I have to use getters like `Foo.bar().apply$mcII$sp(i)` or `apply` with a cast to `Integer`/`int`.

Why is the generic type `Object` and not `Integer`? This also seems to be only the case for types that exist as Java primitives; `List[MyType]` becomes `List<MyType>` in Scala.

Comment: @StuartLC during design time in my IDE. I just wonder why this doesn't happen with non-primitives, e.g., with `List[MyType]` which becomes `List<MyType>` in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced a somewhat similar issue with Swagger not responding well to Scala.

*I don't know why*, but this bug/feature is related to Java's primitives that dont't have setters and getters (like objects). Since the Java compiler can't find a suiting object, it just compiles it down to Object.

Scala collections have made converters to fix this: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html

**The only workaround I can think about is to use:** `Foo.bar.toJava`

Sources: 
[Deserializing Scala list with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52553098/deserializing-scala-list-with-jackson)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581955/2291510

[Spring RequestParam formatter for Scala.Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771485/spring-requestparam-formatter-for-scala-option/39155809#39155809)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This happens due to the fact that [Java does not support primitive types in generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-java-generics-support-primitive-types), generics are a compile time construct only in Java, they do not exist in JVM bytecode, thus they must be convertible to Java's `Object` type, which primitives *cannot*.

If we compile the code using the `-Xprint:jvm` flag, you can see that `List[Int]` actually compiles to the non generic `List`:

```
package com.yuvalitzchakov.github {
  object Foo extends Object {
    private[this] val bar: List = _;
    <stable> <accessor> def bar(): List = Foo.this.bar;
    def <init>(): com.yuvalitzchakov.github.Foo.type = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      Foo.this.bar = scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(scala.Predef.wrapIntArray(Array[Int]{1, 2, 3}));
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

If `Foo.bar` was a `List[Integer]`, this would yield a `List<Integer>` in Java, instead of `List<Object>`

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't compile to the corresponding primitive wrapper types such as `Integer`?

Comment: @beatngu13 That's a good question, I actually do not know why there's no auto lifting to the wrapper types (unless we explicitly annotate `bar` with a `List[Integer]` type).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use collection decorator asJava:

```
val javabar = bar.asJava
```

Comment: I know that this would be a workaround for the problem. I just wonder why the Scala `List[Int]` gets compiled to `List<Object`, i.e., why the generalization to `Object`?